# Drawing and dragging lines using paintComponent without inflicting with any other GUI components within a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paintcomponent, graphics2d

For my binary tree program, I have been using JTextFields as nodes and I have managed to make it so when I click left button and select two of the JTextFields, it will draw a line between them. The problem is if I want to drag the JtextField around, I want the line to be following as well between two of the midpoints of the JTextField.  I don't know if it's possible with using only paintComponent or not. I did try it but it's like a one off thing and it will leave a trail of all the previously drawn lines.
**Here, is the code so far, there are other classes so some of the bits won't work. The code has been fiddled around a bit as well for testing.**

public class BinaryTreeMainPnl extends JPanel {

```
public static Graphics g1;
public int Width = 75;
public int Height = 45;
public String tempNode1 = "";
public int tempNode1Pos = 0;
public int tempNode2Pos = 0;
public String tempNode2 = "";
public static boolean leftBtnSelected;
public static boolean rightBtnSelected;
private static int x1, y1 = 50;
private static int x2, y2 = 500;

JToggleButton leftBtn = new JToggleButton("Left");
JToggleButton rightBtn = new JToggleButton("Right");
JTextField[] myArray = new JTextField[60];
ArrayList<String> nodeNames = new ArrayList<String>();
JFrame MainFrame;
JTextField txtFld1 = new JTextField("Enter Questions here");
JButton btn1 = new JButton("Submit");

public BinaryTreeMainPnl(JFrame frame) {
    super();

    setSize(800, 700);
    MainFrame = frame;
    readInput();
    leftBtn.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 15));
    leftBtn.setForeground(Color.blue);
    leftBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            rightBtn.setSelected(false);
            leftBtnSelected = leftBtn.getModel().isSelected();
            rightBtnSelected = false;

            System.out.println(leftBtnSelected);
            System.out.println(rightBtnSelected);
        }
    });
    add(leftBtn);

    rightBtn.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 15));
    rightBtn.setForeground(Color.green);
    rightBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            leftBtn.setSelected(false);
            rightBtnSelected = rightBtn.getModel().isSelected();
            leftBtnSelected = false;
            System.out.println(leftBtnSelected);
            System.out.println(rightBtnSelected);
        }
    });
    add(rightBtn);

}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    updateLine(g);

}

public void readInput() {
    btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            identifyNodeNames(txtFld1.getText());
            displayNodes(nodeNames);
            new TreeSorting().treeSort(nodeNames);
        }
    });
    this.add(txtFld1);
    this.add(btn1);

}

public void displayNodes(ArrayList<String> nodeNames) {

    for (int i = 0; i < nodeNames.size(); i++) {
        String currentSetText = nodeNames.get(i);
        myArray[i] = new JTextField(currentSetText);
        myArray[i].setEditable(false);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nodeNames.size(); i++) {
        int I = i;
        myArray[I].addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt) {

                int x = evt.getX() + myArray[I].getX();
                int y = evt.getY() + myArray[I].getY();
                myArray[I].setBounds(x, y, myArray[I].getWidth(), myArray[I].getWidth());
                System.out.println(myArray[I] + "dragged");

            }

        });
        myArray[I].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
                if (leftBtnSelected) {
                    if (tempNode1.equals("")) {
                        tempNode1 = myArray[I].getText();
                        System.out.println(tempNode1 + "clicked");
                    } else {
                        tempNode2 = myArray[I].getText();
                        System.out.println(tempNode2 + "Clicked as well");
                        leftBtn.setSelected(false);
                        leftBtnSelected = false;
                        x1 = 40;
                        y1 = 40;
                        x2 = 400;
                        y2 = 400;
                        updateLine(g1);
                        System.out.println("asdasd");

                    }
                }
                if (rightBtnSelected) {

                }
            }

            public void moveComponent(MouseEvent evt) {

            }
        });
        System.out.println("I " + I);
        System.out.println(myArray[I].getText());

        add(myArray[I]);
    }
    MainFrame.revalidate();

}

public int findMidPoint(JTextField temp) {
    Point p = temp.getLocation();
    Dimension d = temp.getSize();
    return p.x + (d.width) / 2;

}
int coun = 0;

public void updateLine(Graphics g) {
    g.drawLine(x1, x2, y1, y2);
    x1 = x1 + 10;
    y1 = y1 + 10;
    y2 = y2 + 10;
    x2 = x2 + 10;
    System.out.println("Line Updated" + coun);
    coun++;
}

public void identifyNodeNames(String answer) {
    int arrayCounter = 0;
    int lastNodePosition = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < answer.length(); i++) {
        char c = answer.charAt(i);
        if (c == ',') {
            nodeNames.add(arrayCounter, answer.substring(lastNodePosition, i + 1).replaceAll(",", "").replaceAll(" ", ""));
            lastNodePosition = i + 1;
            arrayCounter++;
        }

        if (i == answer.length() - 1) {
            nodeNames.add(arrayCounter, answer.substring(lastNodePosition, answer.length()).replaceAll(" ", ""));
        }

    }

}
```

}

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TreeSorting {

```
public static int arrayLength;
String[][] Child;
String root = "";
boolean nodeSorted = false;
int parentCounter = 1;

public void treeSort(ArrayList<String> passedQuestions) {
    // declaring nodes
    arrayLength = passedQuestions.size();
    System.out.println(arrayLength + "ARRAY LENGTH");
    Child = new String[arrayLength][3];
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        Child[i][0] = passedQuestions.get(i);
    }
    //initially calling the mainprocess with parentCounter 1;
    root = Child[0][0];
    mainProcess(1);

}

public void mainProcess(int parentCounter) {

    if (parentCounter < Child.length) {
        System.out.println(parentCounter);
        sortingTree(Child[parentCounter][0], root, 0);  //where the next node is passed on the tree is sorted recursively
        for (int i = 0; i < Child.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(Child[i][0]);
            System.out.println(Child[i][1] + "," + Child[i][2]);
        }

    }
}

public void sortingTree(String CurrentNode, String PreviousNode, int PreviousPosition) {
    nodeSorted = false;// node is not sorted in the beginning
    if (isAfter(CurrentNode.toLowerCase(), PreviousNode.toLowerCase())) {
        System.out.println(Child[PreviousPosition][2]);
        if (Child[PreviousPosition][2] == null) { //checks if the right of the node is empty, if found empty the node is placed there.
            Child[PreviousPosition][2] = CurrentNode;
            nodeSorted = true; // if the node finds a position in the array node is sorted.
        } else {
            sortingTree(CurrentNode, Child[PreviousPosition][2], getPositionInArray(Child[PreviousPosition][2]));
            //if the array position was not empty, the loop will process again this time with the item found in the filled position.
        }
    } else if (Child[PreviousPosition][1] == null) { // if the left of the node is empty, the item will be placed there
        Child[PreviousPosition][1] = CurrentNode;
        nodeSorted = true;
    } else {
        sortingTree(CurrentNode, Child[PreviousPosition][1], getPositionInArray(Child[PreviousPosition][1]));
        //if the array position was not empty, the loop will process again this time with the item found in the filled position.
    }

    if (nodeSorted) { // if the node finds a position in the array, the nodeCounter increments and the next node in the question is processed.
        parentCounter++;
        mainProcess(parentCounter);
    }
}

public int getPositionInArray(String node) {
    int position = 0;
    loop:
    for (int i = 0; i < Child.length; i++) {
        if (Child[i][0].equals(node)) {
            position = i;
            break loop;

        }
    }
    return position;
}

public boolean isAfter(String CurrentNode, String PreviousNode) {
    int loopLength = determineLoopLength(CurrentNode, PreviousNode);
    boolean result = false;
    String tempCheck = "";
    loop:
    for (int i = 0; i < loopLength; i++) {
        if ((int) CurrentNode.charAt(i) > (int) PreviousNode.charAt(i)) {
            result = true;
            break loop;
        }
        if ((int) CurrentNode.charAt(i) < (int) PreviousNode.charAt(i)) {
            result = false;
            break loop;
        } else if (CurrentNode.charAt(i) == PreviousNode.charAt(i) && CurrentNode.length() > PreviousNode.length()) {
            System.out.println("I'm here");
            tempCheck = tempCheck + CurrentNode.charAt(i) + "";
            if (i == loopLength - 1 && tempCheck.equals(PreviousNode)) {
                result = true;
                break loop;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public int determineLoopLength(String CurrentNode, String PreviousNode) {
    int loopLength = 0;
    if (CurrentNode.length() < PreviousNode.length()) {
        loopLength = CurrentNode.length();
    }
    if (PreviousNode.length() < CurrentNode.length()) {
        loopLength = PreviousNode.length();
    } else {
        loopLength = CurrentNode.length();
    }
    return loopLength;
}
```

}

Comment: `"I don't know if it's possible with using only paintComponent or not."` -- yes it's possible. `"I did try it but it's like a one off thing and it will leave a trail of all the previously drawn lines."` -- and if we can see your current best code attempt, preferably posted here with your question as a valid [mcve] and not in a link, we'll be much better able to help you figure out what you may be doing wrong and thereby help you to correct it. Until then, this question will not be easily answered.

Comment: A guess though -- you will want to call the `super.paintComponent(g);` method within your own override, usually as the first call in this method. This will help to clean up any "dirty" pixels including old drawn lines.

Comment: In addition to what Hovercraft is saying, you can provide such an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) by clicking the `edit` link below your question. Paste a Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example in your question, select the code and press the `{}` button to format the code properly.

Answer (score 3):

WTF, been working on this,.....

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DragMyFields extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 1000;
    private static final int PREF_H = 800;
    private static final int COLS = 8;
    private static final int DELTA_Y = 120;
    private static final int MAX_DEPTH = 3;
    private MySimpleTreeNode<JTextField> treeRoot = new MySimpleTreeNode<>();
    private MyMouse myMouse = new MyMouse();

    public DragMyFields() {
        setLayout(null);  // this is *** BAD ***
              // much better would be to create a custom layout

        JTextField field = new JTextField(COLS);
        field.addMouseListener(myMouse);
        field.addMouseMotionListener(myMouse);
        field.setSize(field.getPreferredSize());
        int x = (PREF_W - field.getPreferredSize().width) / 2;
        int y = DELTA_Y;
        field.setLocation(x, y);
        add(field);
        treeRoot.setNode(field);

        recursiveCreateTree(treeRoot, MAX_DEPTH, x, y);
    }

    private void recursiveCreateTree(MySimpleTreeNode<JTextField> node, int depth, int x, int y) {
        if (depth == 0) {
            return;
        }

        JTextField leftField = new JTextField(COLS);
        JTextField rightField = new JTextField(COLS);

        MySimpleTreeNode<JTextField> leftNode = new MySimpleTreeNode<>(leftField);
        MySimpleTreeNode<JTextField> rightNode = new MySimpleTreeNode<>(rightField);
        node.setLeft(leftNode);
        node.setRight(rightNode);

        int multiplier = 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_DEPTH - depth; i++) {
            multiplier *= 2;
        }

        int xL = x - getPreferredSize().width / multiplier;
        int xR = x + getPreferredSize().width / multiplier;
        y += DELTA_Y;

        leftField.setSize(leftField.getPreferredSize());
        rightField.setSize(rightField.getPreferredSize());
        leftField.setLocation(xL, y);
        rightField.setLocation(xR, y);
        leftField.addMouseListener(myMouse);
        leftField.addMouseMotionListener(myMouse);
        rightField.addMouseListener(myMouse);
        rightField.addMouseMotionListener(myMouse);
        add(leftField);
        add(rightField);

        recursiveCreateTree(leftNode, depth - 1, xL, y);
        recursiveCreateTree(rightNode, depth - 1, xR, y);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        recursiveDraw(g, treeRoot);
    }

    private void recursiveDraw(Graphics g, MySimpleTreeNode<JTextField> node) {
        MySimpleTreeNode<JTextField> left = node.getLeft();
        MySimpleTreeNode<JTextField> right = node.getRight();

        Point p = getNodeCenter(node);

        if (left != null) {
            Point p2 = getNodeCenter(left);
            g.drawLine(p.x, p.y, p2.x, p2.y);
            recursiveDraw(g, left);
        }
        if (right != null) {
            Point p2 = getNodeCenter(right);
            g.drawLine(p.x, p.y, p2.x, p2.y);
            recursiveDraw(g, right);
        }

    }

    private Point getNodeCenter(MySimpleTreeNode<JTextField> node) {
        JTextField field = node.getNode();
        Point location = field.getLocation();
        Dimension size = field.getSize();
        return new Point(location.x + size.width / 2, location.y + size.height / 2);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
        Component source = null;
        private Point pressedP;
        private Point pressedLoc;
        private Point parentP;

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getButton() != MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                return;
            }

            source = e.getComponent();
            parentP = source.getParent().getLocationOnScreen();
            pressedLoc = source.getLocationOnScreen();
            pressedP = e.getLocationOnScreen();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            moveComponent(e);
            source = null;
            pressedP = null;
            pressedLoc = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            if (source == null) {
                return;
            }
            moveComponent(e);
        }

        private void moveComponent(MouseEvent e) {
            Point p = e.getLocationOnScreen();
            int x = pressedLoc.x + p.x - pressedP.x - parentP.x;
            int y = pressedLoc.y + p.y - pressedP.y - parentP.y;

            Point newP = new Point(x, y);
            source.setLocation(newP);
            repaint();
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        DragMyFields mainPanel = new DragMyFields();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("DragMyFields");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            createAndShowGui();
        });
    }
}

class MySimpleTreeNode<T> {
    private T node;
    private MySimpleTreeNode<T> left;
    private MySimpleTreeNode<T> right;

    public MySimpleTreeNode() {
        // default constructor
    }

    public MySimpleTreeNode(T node) {
        this.node = node;
    }

    public void setNode(T node) {
        this.node = node;
    }

    public T getNode() {
        return node;
    }

    public MySimpleTreeNode<T> getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    public void setLeft(MySimpleTreeNode<T> left) {
        this.left = left;
    }

    public MySimpleTreeNode<T> getRight() {
        return right;
    }

    public void setRight(MySimpleTreeNode<T> right) {
        this.right = right;
    }

}
```

Comment: I can see where you have your moveComponent method that updates the location of the nodes(JTextFields) but I still can't figure out where you update the location of the line, I can only see where it's drawn. Can you help me with it. But how on earth you were trying to do the exact same thing?

Comment: @CuriousOne: the lines are drawn within a recursive method called by paintComponent, and are based on the calculated center point of each JTextField. The recursion is through my simple tree. As for how on earth was I trying to do the same thing -- I was intrigued by your question and created this on the spot for the question.

Comment: In other words, the lines are created only when they're drawn. That's the only time that they're needed, right?

Comment: Yeah, so when I click a toggle button and click on two of the nodes it should create a line.

Comment: is it not a one off thing, how is the line updating itself when changing the location of the node?

Comment: Or how do I trigger the paintComponent method and pass it the coordinates I want?

Comment: My mouse listener has a private method, `moveComponent(MouseEvent e)` where I move my components around. The last call in that method is to `repaint();`, which is a *request* to have the component repainted. Usually this will get the JVM to call paint/paintComponent on my component and its children.

Comment: @CuriousOne: I have voted to re-open your question, by the way, but it needs more votes to be re-opened.

Comment: so when you repaint, it will trigger the paintComponent method? Am I on the correct path?

Comment: @CuriousOne: almost. Understand that we the programmers do not have full complete control over when or if paint or paintComponent get called, which is why I specifically stated "*request"* above. If too many repaint requests get stacked up, not all of them will result in painting calls. It makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Will play around with the code.

Comment: @CuriousOne: I note a problem with your current latest code -- I can't run it.  At all. It has no main method for one, and it makes a call to code that we don't have, `new TreeSorting().treeSort(nodeNames);`.

Comment: Alright, I have updated the original question with the missing class.

Comment: For the main frame, just create a jframe class and create a new object for the BinaryMainPnl and add it.